# can I change the gesture handling for Google maps for iOS?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google maps already has certain gestures for panning, tilting and zooming of the map. I dont want to use tilt in my map, so when I disable it using setTiltGestures:NO, it now handles two finger panning to scroll through the map as well (same as panning with one finger so its redundant). I wish to use this gesture (pan gesture with two fingers) for something else in the app but it always ends up with the map getting scrolled. How do I find my way around this?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p

Thanks.